# what is AC means in leetcode, is it algorithm technique like DP?

Tags: dynamic-programming, backtracking

I found from various online coding forums, there is a technique called "AC", which looks like "Dynamic Programming" or "Back tracking", but not sure what it is how to use.

Any one has suggestions?

Comment: I don't know much about either of them, but doesn't the type of algorithm to use depend on what problem you're trying to solve? This question is *too broad*, in that sense...

Comment: I am generally interested about what is that design technique, I could not find more meaningful links from web. For example see following leetcode link. [link](https://leetcode.com/discuss/9110/my-ac-solution-using-formula) This says, "here is my AC solution using formula". Not sure what does AC means here.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't downvote your question :)

Comment: AC stands for accepted

Comment: Oh shoot, thank you. I thought it is some algo design technique.

Comment: @CastAway Same here and I was searching for this algorithm for a while lol

Answer (score 43):

AC stands for 'Accepted' solution.

Answer (score 13):

AC stands for "Accepted Code" and is commonly phrased as 'Here is my AC Solution' aka 'Here is my Accepted Code Solution.'

Other acronyms used on leetcode include:

- "compile error" (CE)
- "memory limit exceeded" (MLE)
- "runtime error" (RTE)
- "time limit exceeded" (TLE)
- "wrong answer" (that's WA)

Answer (score 0):

It is a term introduced to computer science by leetcode community   . It means Accepted Code but it is important to know why it could be not accepted, the common reasons are given here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67863886/2815227

It looks like future generations will grap this phrase because almost everywhere asks new engineers algorithm questions and people practice on leetcode like places.

In the real world, there is nothing like that. It would be very funny to talk about your piece of software as "accepted code". There are terms like acceptance criteria and your software needs to meet them on top of passing your tests such as unit and integration tests.